# Magento 2 xml/csv convert

Tags: magento2, import, xml, csv, documentation

I am trying to figure out how that an automatic feed (csv or xml) works within Magento 2. Does anyone know a page with information on how to do so?

I have the xml product feed or the CSV product field but ofcourse i still need to convert their fields into magento fields and visa versa.

Since its the first time that i work with feeds i'm hoping that someone of you knows where i can start reading about this and learn how to do this.

Thanks!